# gulp throws error

Tags: npm, gulp

I am working with gulp version 3.9.1

and i keep getting this error

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './internal/streams/BufferList'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\InviteMe\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:58:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

both local and global versions are matched,

i cleared the npm cache,

i tried to reinstall nodejs

and im still getting this error,

any suggestions????

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You are getting this error when invoking `npm run gulp` or when installing `gulp` via npm?

Comment: when i simply run gulp

Comment: So when invoking the command `gulp`?

Comment: @PeterReid yes...

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: @user6250141 I solved it by manually deleting gulp and some dependencies from the node_modules directory and re installing

Comment: Thanks, I able to fixed the issue same way